# QGIS 3 Plugin Cancel Edits is crashing plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I was using, this method in QGIS2.

```
self.iface.actionCancelEdits().trigger()
```

This method was used, on canceling the edits in the iface. But this method is crashing my plugin on QGIS 3. What is the alternative to this method or am i doing somethign wrong with this method ? I am also using below syntax in QGIS 3, but it is also not working.

```
self.dlg.showNormal()
```